# Accessing a single record from a simple model

Tags: ember.js

I'm starting simple, trying to display a single value from a simple model.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491509/282194) to ["accessing the model from the template"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14491347/282194) suggests that it's necessary to extend ObjectController.  At this point, there's have no application logic, so it doesn't seem like a controller (or a view) is really needed yet.

Likewise, there are no routes yet, so it doesn't seem like anything should be needed beyond App.IndexRoute.

The single object in the dictionary fixture has a title property with the value `Hello Ember`.  I'm expecting to see that text displayed between two hard-coded arrows.  Instead, all I get is the arrows.

The Index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dictionary</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main body of the application -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <p>Title: --&gt;{{title}}&lt;--</p>
    </script>

    <!-- ... Ember.js and other JavaScript dependencies ... -->
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app/application.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routers/router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/models/dictionary_model.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/dictionary_controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then the JavaScript:

```
// application.js
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

// router.js
App.Router.map(function() {
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('dictionary', 0);
    }
});

// dictionary_model.js
App.Dictionary = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Dictionary.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 0,
    title: "Hello Ember"
}];

// dictionary_controller.js
App.DictionaryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're reading in the documentation that's contradicting, please update your question with the contradicting statements so they can be fixed.

The controller really only need be defined if you need to add additional computed properties, actions, or other methods.  In your case you are correct in that it needn't be defined.

That being said, the `application` template (or unnamed template as in your case) is the root of your ember app.  Any child routes/resources will be rendered in the `{{outlet}}` located in the application template(examples below).

The `index` route is a route underneath the `application` route.  Resources are considered routes that can have children and generally associated with a model.

All this comes up to the main problem you're seeing.  You've returned your model from the index route, but you are attempting to use it in the application route's template.

Here's a simplified version of your code

#### Code

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter= DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('dictionary', 0);
    }
});

App.Dictionary = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Dictionary.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 0,
    title: "Hello Ember"
}];
```

#### Templates

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Application Template</h2>
    Here we Are in the Application Template

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h2>Index Template</h2>

    {{title}}
  </script>
```

#### Example in action

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/443/edit

Comment: Aha! The nuance of the application route/template being different from the index route/template was definitely lost on me.  The routing guide refers to them together as "You get a few routes for free: the ApplicationRoute and the IndexRoute (corresponding to the / path)." and even when I read further down, I didn't catch the distinction of what they each do (the application lives at / after all).  I'll pull out the bit about the how to set up routes and put that into its own question.